# Generate layer preview icons

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, legend

QGIS uses small image preview icons for its layers in the legend and layer tree. How can I create these for a given layer as an image object (`QIcon` or `QImage` I presume)?

[image]

As I am looking for a PyQGIS solution, here is my existing code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
```

How do I get this layer's preview icon?

Answer (score 1):

For a QgsVectorLayer:

```
>>> renderer = layer.renderer()
>>> legendSymbolItems = renderer.legendSymbolItems()
>>> legendSymbolItem = legendSymbolItems[0]  # more if more classes
>>> symbol = legendSymbolItem.symbol()
>>> symbol.asImage(QSize(256, 128))
<PyQt5.QtGui.QImage object at 0x7fd869197d80>
```

Comment: I have been using `QgsSymbolLayerUtils.symbolPreviewIcon(layer.renderer().symbol(), QSize(16, 16))`. Should work as well, if you need a `QIcon` :)

Comment: Oooh, that has some very nice related functions. Thank you! https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.32/core/QgsSymbolLayerUtils.html